# Identify a view used in multiple activities

Tags: java, android, android-view, android-spinner

I have a spinner that i use over several activities. In one of them, I have to modify one of the parameters of the spinner. How could i identify from the spinner itself (without passing any extra parameter) the activities where the spinner will be inflated?

Comment: Do you mean that you have a custom spinner class and you want the class to be aware which activity is using it?

Answer (score 1):

Depends a bit on your app - but I see 2 approaches for now:

## 1 You could add a tag to the spinner

## 2 You check the context of the spinner